# Apps won't show in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, pinax

I've read all the other threads but I still don't get why my apps are not showing up in Django admin. Everything else works fine.

My apps are in settings.py

I have admin.autodiscover in my root urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()



urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', direct_to_template, {
    "template": "homepage.html",
}, name="home"),

url(r'^admin/invite_user/$', 'signup_codes.views.admin_invite_user', name="admin_invite_user"),
url(r'^account/signup/$', "signup_codes.views.signup", name="acct_signup"),

(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),
(r'^profiles/', include('basic_profiles.urls')),
(r'^notices/', include('notification.urls')),
(r'^announcements/', include('announcements.urls')),
(r'^tagging_utils/', include('tagging_utils.urls')),
(r'^attachments/', include('attachments.urls')),
(r'^comments/', include('threadedcomments.urls')),
#
(r'^wayfinder/', include('wayfinder.urls')),
(r'^site/', include('jsite.urls')),
(r'^kiosk/', include('kiosk.urls')),
(r'^navigator/', include('navigator.urls')),
(r'^location/', include('location.urls')),
(r'^event/', include('event.urls')),
#(r'^news_reader/', include('news_reader.urls')),
#(r'^weather_reader/', include('weather_reader.urls')),

(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
)

if settings.SERVE_MEDIA:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^site_media/', include('staticfiles.urls')),
)
```

All my apps have an admin.py file containing something like

```
from django.contrib import admin
from event.models import Event

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
                'short_name',
                'long_name',
                'locations',
                'categories',
                'description',
                'phone',
                'email',
                'url_source',
                'url_location',
                'external_ref',
                'show_event'
            )

admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
```

And I have restarted the server over and over ;-)

I am building on top of Pinax, but from my reading, it shouldn't change anything. Any clue what might be wrong ?

Comment: The usual reason is that settings.py does not mention the apps in the INSTALLED_APPS section, as Code Duck says. Do you have this set up correctly?

Comment: Have you done `syncdb` ?

Comment: figured out the problem. one of my admin was refering to deprecated newforms, I didn't butter fixing it right away. It seems that the second time (refreshing page) the admin was called, the error was dropped and the admin showed but without all the models that were following the one containing the error. as it was at the top of the apps I've added, none were show except the Pinax apps that were at the top of the list. 
never dismiss errors ;-)

I'll give it to code duck

thanks to all who helped ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have your apps in the INSTALLED_APPS section in settings.py? 
Make sure it has your apps listed there. My section reads

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.sites',
'squick.items',
'cowsite.search',
'cowsite.posts',
```

)

for instance. I'm pretty sure for security, they won't show up in the admin unless they are in installed apps. I think I had this same issue, where I couldn't get cowsite to show up in the admin.

[The Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-index-page) say about the admin page: "By default, it displays all the apps in INSTALLED_APPS that have been registered with the admin application, in alphabetical order"

Comment: the apps are in the installed_apps list. I should not that the whole project work, all the models from my apps are generated correctly and works in different views and 10s of templates, but I don't see them in the admin...

Comment: add `admin.site.register(ThisModel)` to your admin.py file in your app folder.

Answer (score 7):

By coincidence I had the same problem this morning.  Briefly, this is what worked for me (see references for details):

In the top level directory of MyApp (ie same directory as models.py, etc.) I added a python module admin.py, containing:

```
from models import ThisModel, ThatModel
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(ThisModel)
admin.site.register(ThatModel)
```

Then in mysite directory I did syncdb and runserver, and ThisModel and ThatModel were in the admin interface.

Does that work for you?

Best wishes

Ivan

** References

(I am a new member so I am allowed to post one hyperlink only!)

[Django tutorial: Make the poll app modifiable in the admin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/?from=olddocs#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin)

There was also a query on the Pinax google group recently titled, "How to add my app to Admin in a Pinax project?"

Answer (score 5):

Are you logging in to admin as a superuser? If not, it could be a permissions problem.

Comment: Not everyone who can log in to admin has is_superuser right. Doublecheck that you do.

Comment: Yes, logged in with super_user privileges

Comment: Notably, a user *can* login to the admin without is_superuser, and may only see *some* apps/models. (I was stumped by this problem for a bit, where my user who was is_staff and is_admin could see some but not all apps/models in the admin. When I made sure I was also is_superuser, everything expected appeared.)

Comment: It is not so much of a bug but a feature. That's the whole idea of superuser - to see all apps. While normal admin staff only see what they're allowed to see. Which apps/models are visible for non-superuser is controlled by permissions model.

Comment: Anybody who has read this far should take a moment to lay eyes on the permissions!  I was fairly certain I was a superuser and I was wrong!  I wasted a lot of time as a result...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of django you're using but the current docs suggest **including** the admin urls.

```
 ('^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

Comment: I think that comes from pinax. The problem is not acessing the admin, that i can. It's really having acess to my app's models. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For other's coming across this, I had the same issue due to grappelli.dashboard being in the installed apps but not actually installed in the virtualenv, so do a pip freeze and ensure all your requirements are actually installed.

Answer (score 0):

add your app name in "settings.py" file installed app.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',


]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other solutions did not work for you, try to load your admin dashboard in a **different browser**. One of my apps was not displaying on the admin dashboard while I was using Google Chrome. After trying multiple answers others suggested, I decided to use Firefox instead. Voila! I was finally able to see my app on the admin dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't answer Antony's question. Are you logging in as a superuser, or at least with a user with add/edit rights for the applications? If not, you won't see them.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, what worked for me was changing this line in urls.py:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

to

```
url('^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

(Removing the **r** in the first bit of code)
For some reason I am not aware of, the Polls became visible in admin after that.